# I need Help on validation rules

Tags: administration, validation

I need assistance on creating Validation Rules on Account Object-

- If the Vehicle Makes(Editable) field **is** populated, then the Franchise_Type_c must be populated.
- If the Franchise_Type_c field **is NOT** populated, the following error message should be displayed”  The Franchise Type is required”

These are custom fields on the Account Object.

- Franchise Type (Franchise_Type__c)
- Market Type (Market_Type__c)
- Vehicle Makes(Editable) (DT_Input__c)

Comment: This isn't a specific question. You just seem to be asking us to do your job for you.

Comment: appu - Have you approved the edit? it looks like 3/4 of your requirements are gone?

Comment: Yes saariko,I need solution for this one only.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is pretty much detailed, and you know your validation rules, I believe the process is pretty straight forward.

2 issues:

1. Do you need 1 or 2 validation rules? (you can have what you need in a single or 2 seperated rules)
2. Your first requirement is not needed. Since Franchise_Type__c is a required field.

**BTW, did you think to change that in the Custom Field settings?  You could change the Field 'Franchise_Type__c' into a required field.**

Go to create a new validation rule

[image]

- Click on New

Give a "Rule Name" and add Description

You than need to enter your criteria.

[image]

The Criteria will look something like this:

[image]